# Using jQuery $.ajax with Angular - the DOM isn't updated

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to render different content based on a value obtained via an XHR to the server:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header" ng-controller="MyController">
      <div ng-switch on="myScopeVar">
        <div ng-switch-when="value1">
```

So, the value of MyController's variable myScopeVar is set with:

```
angular.module('webguiApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, $cookies) {
    ...
    request.contentType = 'application/json';
    request.dataType = 'json';
    request.data = JSON.stringify({...});
    $.ajax(request)
      .done(function(data) {
           $scope.myScopeVar = data.serverValue;
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
           $scope.myScopeVar = 'errorStatusValue';
      });
```

Now, angular initializes as soon as the controller is defined, in which case $scope.myScopeVar is still undefined. How can I get angular to wait (not render that part) until the XHR completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using jQuery's ajax instead of Angular's `$http` service. When you use functions that are "outside" of Angular, it doesn't know to run a `digest` cycle, so nothing is updated. You can manually force a digest with `$scope.$apply()`, but that is usually bad practice.

**[Angular $http docs (click).](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)**

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('foo.txt').then(function(resp) {
    $scope.myScopeVar = resp.data;
  }, function() {
    $scope.myScopeVar = 'errorStatusValue'
  });
})
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/HDGgnboJbOIrgc5mDrTp?p=preview)**